# 404 error after putting WordPress on my vps server but homepage does work

Tags: wordpress, iis, http-status-code-404, vps, permalinks

So my WordPress site worked perfectly on my localhost, until I transferred it to my Windows Server machine. Now, only the index still works; the other pages give me a 404 error.

I have already tried changing permalink options and other fixes, but nothing has worked.

How I can get my other pages online?

Comment: my site is http://www.obedado.tk so that u can see it urself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its too easy

1. go to wp-admin in your WordPress.
2. in dashboard go to settings.
3. in settings go to Permalink Settings.
4. in Permalink Settings if your Common Settings set on Day and name or anything else change it to Plain.
5. save the setting and go to your web pages.
6. if every things work correctly back to Permalink Settings and change Common Settings on Day and name or anything you want.

Comment: didn't work as i said before, but thx for taking your time to reply!!

Comment: I hope you can solved your problem as fast as possible.

Comment: I reinstalled wp and tried ur fix and it worked thanks bro!